# how can i get all attribute data from ManyToMany field Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i want to get all attribute data of articles in `SetRundown` forms like `title, category, author` via `ManyToManyfield` i want to show all article in Rundown form with title category and author name can anybody know how can i do this...? if i run my code with `{% render_field form.articles %}` then it will show the all articles title but i want the category and author name too with titles....

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, help_text="Short title")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class SetRundown(models.Model):
    pool_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class SetRundownForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SetRundown
        fields = ['pool_title', 'time_pool', 'articles']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SetRundownForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['articles'].queryset = Article.objects.filter(story_status='fr')
```

create_form.html

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {% render_field form.pool_title type="text" %}

    {% render_field form.time_pool type="menu"  %}

    {% for article in form.articles  %}
    
    {{ article.title }}
    {{ article.category }}
    {{ article.author.username }}
    
    {% endfor  %}

    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `.queryset` of the `.field`:

```
{% for article in form.articles.field.queryset %}
    {{ article.title }}
    {{ article.category }}
    {{ article.author.username }}    
{% endfor %}
```

In your `SetRundownForm`, you can make use of [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to avoid an *N+1 problem*:

```
class SetRundownForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SetRundown
        fields = ['pool_title', 'time_pool', 'articles']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SetRundownForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['articles'].queryset = Article.objects.select_related(
            'author'
        ).filter(story_status='fr')
```

Comment: dear it's not rendering anything in template...?

Comment: @afi: yes there was a typo, it is `.field`, not `.fields` :s.